# How to echo `single quote` when using single quote to wrap special characters in shell?

Tags: shell, quoting

I'm reading shell tutorial today from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-quoting-mechanisms.htm

In which it mentions:

> If a single quote appears within a string to be output, you should not put the whole string within single quotes instead you whould preceed that using a backslash () as follows:

```
echo 'It\'s Shell Programming'
```

I tried this on my centos server, it doesn't work, a `>` prompts out to hint me type more.

I was wondering, since two single quotes transform every special characters into normal characters,  which include escape symbol `\`, but exclude itself, the `'`,
how should I represent a single single quote `'`in a single-quoted phrase?

Comment: Why don't use `echo It\'s Shell Programming` or `echo "It's Shell Programming"`?

Comment: @cuonglm, because I may use phrase like `echo Wow, I'm going to have lots of $$$$$$ now`

Comment: So you should use double quotes, and escape `$`, too. Something like `echo Wow, I\'m going to have lots of \$\$\$\$\$\$ now` or just `echo Wow, I\'m going to have lots of '$$$$$$' now`

Comment: @cuonglm, yes, I can do it, and I know how I can do it. But the tutorial I've been reading seems is confident about that there is a way to escape single quote inside single-quoted phrases, but the given example of the tutorial doesn't work. So I'm wondering someone may know the solution.

Comment: @cuonglm The second solution of your 3rd floor is valuable. So I gave a vote.

Comment: How about this? `echo 'It'"'"'s Shell Programming'`. I just divide it as 3 strings, the first and the last surrounded by single quotes, but the middle one have a single quote surrounded by double quotes.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The tutorial is wrong.

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) says:

> A single-quote cannot occur within single-quotes.

Here's some alternatives:

```
echo $'It\'s Shell Programming'  # ksh, bash, and zsh only, does not expand variables
echo "It's Shell Programming"   # all shells, expands variables
echo 'It'\''s Shell Programming' # all shells, single quote is outside the quotes
echo 'It'"'"'s Shell Programming' # all shells, single quote is inside double quotes
```

Further reading: [Quotes - Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#Examples)

Comment: One more: `echo 'It''s Shell Programming'` - zsh with `rc_quotes` option set (and the rc shell too) - a pair of single quotes inside single quotes represents a single single quote.

Comment: I sometimes use `q="'"` and `qq='"'` to make this cleaner.  This then allows `echo "It${q}s ${qq}Shell Programming${qq}"` (curly brackets are needed given trailing letters).  POSIX-safe. The outer layer must be double-quoted.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else comes along for putting a mix of single and double quotes into a file, this is working too:

```
cat > its-shell-programing.txt << __EOF__
echo $'It\'s Shell Programming'
echo "It's Shell Programming"
echo 'It'\''s Shell Programming'
echo 'It'"'"'s Shell Programming'
__EOF__
```

Everything the shell might see as a variable though must be escaped by a backslash:

```
cat >> its-shell-programing.txt << __EOF__
echo \$It\'s Shell Programming
__EOF__
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
sed "s/'"'/&\\&&/g
     s/.*/'"'&'"'/
' <<IN
$arbitrary_value
IN
```

To safely shell quote a value line per line.

Shell depending, you might also have the option to do:

```
printf %q\\n "$arbitrary_value"
```

Though I usually prefer to do:

```
a=$(alias "a=$arbitrary_value" a); a=${a#*=}
```

A more manual approach could look like:

```
sq(){ set \' "$1"
      while case $2 in (*\'*) :;;
      (*) ! RETURN="$1$2'"     ;;esac
      do  set "$1${2%%\'*}'\''" "${2#*\'}"
      done
}
```

...which is, at least, fork-free.

Comment: I totally have no idea about what you are talking about, except the phrase `printf %q\\n "$arbitrary_value"`, others are too complicate.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "He said to me, \"I've seen that.\""
```

Seems to me to be the simplest way to return the text:

```
He said to me, "I've seen that."
```

Comment: Oops, code was deleted.
'code' echo "He said to me, \"I've seen that\""

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that it seems to be basically reiterating alternative 2 of [Mikel's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187654/377345) (literal single quote enclosed in double quoted string). You may want to consider expanding it so that the difference to that answer becomes more visible; otherwise it would be best placed as a comment to that answer (once you have sufficient reputation).

Comment: @AdminBee I guess the difference here is that this solution is escaping the internal double quotes.  I don't think that's covered in another answer.

Comment: @terdon True, but the original problem is only about single quotes in single-quoted text, and internal double-quotes are never mentioned, so I wonder how this answer adds anything new ...

Comment: Ah right, true @AdminBee.