# Changing the Date Format Displayed from a Text File

Tags: shell, awk, grep, date

This code

```
grep -i 'logged in' path-to-file | tail | awk '{ print $6,"logged in at",substr($2,1,8),"on",$1"."; }' | sed 's/"//g'
```

will output

nickname logged in at 22:06:58 on 2017-12-22.

What I want is to output like this:

nickname logged in at 10:06:58 pm on December 22, 2017.

Comment: [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unix `date` command can print dates in whatever format you want to. Using the `--date` flag you can print a date and time different from the current date and time. However, for the `date` command to parse the date you have to remove the *on* in your input date. You can use the following sed command:

```
sed -r 's,\s+on\s+, ,g'
```

Combined with your desired output format, you get:

```
date --date="$(echo '22:06:58 on 2017-12-22' | sed -r 's,\s+on\s+, ,g')" '+%r on %B %d, %Y'
```

Now, you only have to combine this with your awk command, which can be done easily assuming that you always have the same format *"username logged in at date"*. Note that you can have the *on* not printed from `awk` at all, so the `sed` call is no longer necessary:

```
while read line
do
    echo $line | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "}' | tr -d '\n'
    date --date="$(echo $line | awk '{print $5" "$7}' | tr -d '.')" '+%r on %B %d, %Y'
done
```

For the example you gave, this prints (with locale `en-NZ`):

> nickname logged in at 10:06:58 PM on December 22, 2017

Comment: The only text in my .sh file is the "grep...sed... In your answer the block starting from while read line (which I'actually m totally clueless about), can I simply copy-paste that and replace my script altogether? I think I like your answer, but I'm still confused on how to combine it with my awk...

Comment: No, use your current command and write `| while read ...` behind it