# Output Bash argument with multiple single quotes to file verbatim (without losing any single quotes)

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, printf

I'm trying to:

1. Accept input in bash and store it *verbatim* to a file
2. *cat* the contents of the file.

Any special characters should also be written *verbatim* to the file.

## Sample Input

```
./verbatim.sh -a smb 'ngrep -i -d $INTERFACE 's.?a.?m.?b.?a.*[[:digit:]]''
```

### Expected output

*Inner single quotes should remain*
[image]

```
-a smb 'ngrep -i -d $INTERFACE 's.?a.?m.?b.?a.*[[:digit:]]''
```

### Actual output

*Inner quotes are stripped*

```
-a smb 'ngrep -i -d $INTERFACE s.?a.?m.?b.?a.*[[:digit:]]'
```

## Code

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Script Name: verbatim.sh
chars='[ !"#$&()*,;<>?\^`{|}]'
for arg
do
    if [[ $arg == *\'* ]]
    then
        arg=\""$arg"\"
    elif [[ $arg == *$chars* ]]
    then
        arg="'$arg'"
    fi
    allargs+=("$arg")    # ${allargs[@]} is to be used only for printing
done
printf '%s\n' "${allargs[*]}" > /tmp/pse.tmp

cat /tmp/pse.tmp
```

I'm not sure if bash can accomplish what I am asking or not?

Would this be better to accept using read or IFS?  The goal of my script is to append the user's input to a file that will be used as a "quick reference" for a particular service.

Comment: You don't have any "inner single quotes": https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187651/how-to-echo-single-quote-when-using-single-quote-to-wrap-special-characters-in Also: use [`printf %q`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-printf) or [`"${var@Q}"`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) instead of rolling your own quoting

Comment: I've highlighted the inner single quotes in a picture that i just attached to the question.

Comment: Did you read the linked post? You don't have any "inner single quotes". In `'ngrep -i -d $INTERFACE 's.?a.?m.?b.?a.*[[:digit:]]''`, you have one single-quoted string `'ngrep -i -d $INTERFACE '` followed by unquoted `s.?a.?m.?b.?a.*[[:digit:]]`, followed by the single-quoted empty string `''`.

Comment: No wonder this doesn't work, thanks @muru

Comment: This question is not about accepting input and storing it verbatim. It's about _giving_ input verbatim to a script on the command line.  At least that is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

#### The question on the title

Once a variable contains an specific string, it wont be expanded a second time (if quoted).

So, for the example case you presented (convert all `'` to `'\''`):

```
var='-a smb '\''ngrep -i -d $INTERFACE '\''s.?a.?m.?b.?a.*[[:digit:]]'\'''\'''
```

Or, reduced a little (not actually needed, but nicer to remove consecutive `''`):

```
var='-a smb '\''ngrep -i -d $INTERFACE '\''s.?a.?m.?b.?a.*[[:digit:]]'\'\'
```

Will print this (the string you want):

```
$ echo "$var"
-a smb 'ngrep -i -d $INTERFACE 's.?a.?m.?b.?a.*[[:digit:]]''
```

And will give an script that same string:

```
$ ./verbatim.sh "$var"
```

If the (`verbatim.sh`) script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf '<%s>' "$@"; echo
```

It will print:

```
$ ./verbatim.sh "$var"
<-a smb 'ngrep -i -d $INTERFACE 's.?a.?m.?b.?a.*[[:digit:]]''>
```

a verbatim string of what you wrote.

#### Write to file:

If you want to write that input to a file, you can extend the `verbatim.sh` script to:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf '<%s>' "$@"; echo
printf '%s\n' "$var" > /tmp/pse.tmp
```

And then:

```
$ cat /tmp/pse.tmp
-a smb 'ngrep -i -d $INTERFACE 's.?a.?m.?b.?a.*[[:digit:]]''
```

Will give you the output you are asking for.

### Problems

The above works because I have been careful to process the string inside "$var" as a **single** string, not arguments.

- The first thing your script do is to ask for a list of arguments in:

  ```
  for arg do .......
  ```

  There is one single argument: an string. If you need a list of arguments the process must be entirely different.
- Then you try to quote each separate argument with double or single quotes. No, that won't work either.
- And,reading the contents of the string you provide, you seem to be trying to build a command and execute it. That is even worse. You **must** read [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Then, maybe, edit this question to use arrays for arguments.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this @issac, I appreciate it

Comment: @brakertech I am glad it has been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.

If you run the following

```
     myprog a
     myprog \a
     myprog "a"
     myprog 'a'
```

then in all 4 cases the value that `myprog` will get for the first argument will be a pointer to the string `"a"`, and you can't tell which you were given. Therefore you can't write out what you were given verbatim This is because the arguments are processed before `myprog` is even invoked.